# Is completely re-writing an answer while keeping its original meaning ok?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

Yesterday [an old, but popular answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967976/what-are-the-allowed-tags-inside-a-li/4968037#4968037) was [completely re-written](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4968037/revisions).

While my original answer certainly wasn't perfect grammar-wise, I do find the edit a bit extreme. Is the edit within community guidelines, or should I roll it back?

Comment: Rolling it back is up to you. If you think it's still the answer you intended it to be, just let it be. Looking at the particular edit, I only see it as an improvement. A substantial edit, but not harmful IMHO.

Comment: Yes, not only is this general practice perfectly acceptable, this specific case looks like a significant positive improvement over the original. Leave it be. Please don't take edits personally. Editors aren't saying that what you posted "wasn't good enough", they're just demonstrating that it can be made even better with collaborative effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not happy with the edit, then by all means, roll it back.  Perhaps, take parts of the edit that make sense to you and edit it yourself with these things in mind.

An edit should not change the meaning of the post.  While it looks to retain the same meaning, it is up to you.

Comment: The content of the edit is great. I just found it strange that one would edit an answer so much. I'll leave it how it is. Thanks for the infos everyone.

Comment: Think of it as someone taking the time because your work is definitely worth it.